# Create column with multiple data frames and multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am looking at football data and trying to add an opponent column, but am struggling with the way that the data frames are organized.

****EDIT****

```
defense = {'week': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'team': ['GB', 'MIA', 'CHI',       'DET', 'GB', 'MIA', 'CHI', 'DET']}
games = {'week': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'winner': ['GB', 'MIA', 'GB', 'DET'], 'loser': ['CHI', 'DET', 'MIA', 'CHI']}
def_df = pd.DataFrame(data=defense)
games_df = pd.DataFrame(data=games)
```

def_df

```
  team  week
0   GB     1
1  MIA     1
2  CHI     1
3  DET     1
4   GB     2
5  MIA     2
6  CHI     2
7  DET     2
```

games_df

```
  loser  week winner
0   CHI     1     GB
1   DET     1    MIA
2   MIA     2     GB
3   CHI     2    DET
```

I am looking to add an defense['Opponent'] column based on that week.

```
  team  week    Opponent 
0   GB     1    CHI
1  MIA     1    DET
2  CHI     1    GB
3  DET     1    MIA
4   GB     2    MIA
5  MIA     2    GB
6  CHI     2    DET
7  DET     2    CHI
```

[image: def_2017 dataframe]

[image: schedule dataframe]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using a nested dictionary mapping:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
for row in games_df.itertuples(index=False):
    d[row.week].update({row.winner: row.loser, row.loser: row.winner})

def_df['opponent'] = def_df.apply(lambda x: d[x['week']][x['team']], axis=1)

print(def_df)

  team  week opponent
0   GB     1      CHI
1  MIA     1      DET
2  CHI     1       GB
3  DET     1      MIA
4   GB     2      MIA
5  MIA     2       GB
6  CHI     2      DET
7  DET     2      CHI
```

An equally valid alternative using tuple keys, which avoids `collections`:

```
d = {}
for row in games_df.itertuples(index=False):
    d[(row.week, row.winner)] = row.loser
    d[(row.week, row.loser)] = row.winner

def_df['opponent'] = def_df.set_index(['week', 'team']).index.map(d.get)
```

Comment: @Parfait, actually, I did mean `defaultdict(dict)`, this just lets me use `dict.update` without having to initialize a dictionary for the first time a week is encountered.

Comment: I've also added a version without `collections`.

Comment: The defaultdict worked!  I need to do some research to understand why, but thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

### Updated

#### Create a column of opponents

```
opponent_list = []
for team, week in zip(def_df['team'],def_df['week']):
    for gameweek, winner, loser in zip(games_df['week'],games_df['winner'],games_df['loser']):
        if gameweek == week and (winner ==team or loser ==team):
            if winner == team:
                opponent_list.append(loser)
            else:
                opponent_list.append(winner)
def_df['opponent'] = opponent_list
```

Comment: Tried running and get 'Key Error: 0'